# Change flask running port in VScode debugger

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I do have a flask application running on port `8000` because i have logstash running on port `5000`.

`app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)`

i can run my app successfully. but when i use VScode debugger it throws

> OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

because the debugger tries to run my app on port `5000`.
i tried editing `.vscode/launch.json` and set `"port": 8000` inside `configurations` but the error still the same. how can i tell the VScode to run my app with debugger on another port?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options

Comment: @abdusco ty. `"args" : ["--port", "8000"]` did the trick.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add `args` key to your debug configuration and set the port there:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options

```
{
    "name": "Python: startup.py",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/startup.py",
    "args" : ["run", "--port", "8000"]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically for "Python: Current File"? For example for startup.py do port 5050, for foo.py do port 6060?

Comment: Seems possible. You can use `program: ${file}` to run the current file, then use a custom input variable to generate a random port (`python -c 'import random; print(random.randint(4000, 5000))'`). See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables

Comment: can this be read from the .env file? or a config?